# Can we add more than five tab bar in ios sdk?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I want to add a sixth tab bar item in my project. When I try that I am getting the "More" tab but when I am clicking on the "More" tab nothing happens. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please, provide the relevant code in your delegate, otherwise it would be pretty impossible to say what causing this...

Comment: k. Please tell me we can add 6 tab bar in ios sdk correct......

Comment: you can have 6 tabs or more, but in this case, only four will show their icons, and the fifth will be the standard "More..." tab which leads you to the separate list controller for the rest of the tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use custom tab bar from here: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/infinitabbar

Or even this one:
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ciexpandabletabbar

Answer (score 9):

In swift, subclass `UITabBarController` and implement:

```
override var traitCollection: UITraitCollection {
    let realTraits = super.traitCollection
    let lieTrait = UITraitCollection.init(horizontalSizeClass: .regular)
    return UITraitCollection(traitsFrom: [realTraits, lieTrait])
}
```

Comment: i am developing a *IPad* application and it did not work for me, any suggestion?

Comment: and made a class for *UITAbbar* not tab bar controller

Comment: That's a great idea!

Answer (score 8):

As of iOS 9 (and possibly 8), there is a simple way to do this. I do not recommend shipping apps using this trick - six tabs is pretty cramped on a 4s or 5 - but it's neat to know.

Notice that iPad tab bars can have more than five tabs just fine without a "more" item.

Apple's new way of determining "tablet or not?" is with size classes.

So, subclass `UITabBarController` and implement:

```
-(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection
{
  UITraitCollection
  *realTraits = [super traitCollection],
  *lieTrait = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular];
  return [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithTraitsFromCollections:@[realTraits, lieTrait]];
}
```

Add six child view controllers to it, and voila! It looks like Apple practices what they preach, in this case!

(* Note that this will also lie about the horizontal size class to the view controllers in the tabs. You may wish to call `- setOverrideTraitCollection:forChildViewController:` at an opportune time, possibly in an override of `setViewControllers:`, to "override" their trait collections back to the real one. That way they won't get confused and try to display inappropriately wide variants of their layout.)

[Edit to add much later:
As of iOS 12 or so this trick has an interesting side effect: for 5 or fewer tabs, it turns the tab bar into iPad-style with the titles to the right of the icons.]

Comment: The answer itself seems to work perfectly. But not in all cases. For example, it seems that it especially messes up the portrait/landscape orientation of the UITabBarController when using AVPlayerViewController.

Comment: i am developing an *IPad* application in swift in the *Land scape* orientation, and this solution is not working for me

Comment: This solution won't affect iPads at all. iPads are already horizontally regular. UITabBarController may have another upper limit to the number of tabs; if you need more, you might consider just using a row of buttons instead.

Answer (score 4):

Make a CustomTabBarVC inherit it from UITabBarController and implement following it will make it possible for you.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBarVC: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override var traitCollection: UITraitCollection {
        let realTraits = super.traitCollection
        let fakeTraits = UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .regular)
        return UITraitCollection(traitsFrom: [realTraits, fakeTraits])
    }
}
```

[image]